# QScrollArea is expanding instead of scrolling

Tags: python, pyqt4, qscrollarea

I have a `QScrollArea` and I'll add some other widgets to it. What I want is that the `QScrollArea` starts scrolling when the widgets in it extend its size.

But instead the scroll area starts expanding itself.

Here's the code I've used:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Widget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.vbox)

    def add_button(self):
        tmp = QtGui.QPushButton("...", self)
        self.vbox.addWidget(tmp)

class ScrollArea(QtGui.QScrollArea):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QScrollArea.__init__(self, parent)

        self.vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()

        self.w = Widget(self)
        self.setWidget(self.w)    #set the widget to provide scrolling for here
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.w)

        self.plus = QtGui.QPushButton("button", self)
        self.connect(self.plus, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.add_button)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.plus)

        self.setLayout(self.vbox)

    def add_button(self):
        self.w.add_button()

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
main = ScrollArea()
main.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I also tried to set the layout of the child widget `self.w` in the class `ScrollArea` instead of in its own class but it had the same effect.

Comment: According to the documentation the `QScrollArea` is able to show *one* widget inside, and you have to add the widget using the `setWidget` method, not build your own layout and manually apply it on the area. See [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qscrollarea.html#details).

Comment: Yes, you are right, I forgot that one. But adding the line `self.setWidget(self.w)` unfortunately doesn't change the behaviour. According to the documentation it should provide now scrolling for the widget `self.w` but somehow it doesn't.

Comment: You are still calling `setLayout`. *That* is what is breaking the behaviour.

Comment: You are right, I got it working! And if one wants to add children to the widget the scroll area takes care off, it is important to call `setSizeContraint(QLayout.SetMinAndMaxSize)` (or with a comparable argument) for that widget's layout.
I'll just summarize that in an answer below if you don't mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already pointed out by Bakuriu it is important that one doesn't apply its own layout to the `QScrollArea` but just specifies one widget (denoted with `w` in the following) via `setWidget` as the one the scroll area should take care off.

It is important to set the layout of `w` *before* you call `setWidget` and if one wants to add several other children to `w` (like the `QPushButton`s in the above problem) it is also important to call `setSizeConstraint` for `w`'s layout (e.g. `setSizeContraint(QLayout.SetMinAndMaxSize)`, see [this](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qlayout.html#SizeConstraint-enum) for more options). Follow [this link](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qscrollarea.html#details) for more details on the behaviour of `QScrollArea`.

The following code is a working example:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Widget(QtGui.QWidget):
    """ Here we add more buttons, if the size of the buttons exceeds the size of the widget scrolling starts. """
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.vbox.setSizeConstraint(QtGui.QLayout.SetMinAndMaxSize)
        self.setLayout(self.vbox)

    def add_button(self):
        tmp = QtGui.QPushButton("...", self)
        self.vbox.addWidget(tmp)

class ScrollArea(QtGui.QScrollArea):
    """ This scroll area only handles one widget for which scrolling should be provided. """
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QScrollArea.__init__(self, parent)

        self.w = Widget()
        self.setWidget(self.w)    #set the widget to provide scrolling for here

    def add_button(self):
        self.w.add_button()

class MainWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    """ Use this widget to arrange the QScrollArea and the QPushButton. """
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)

        self.vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.scroll = ScrollArea(self)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.scroll)

        self.plus = QtGui.QPushButton("button", self)
        self.connect(self.plus, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.add_button)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.plus)

        self.setLayout(self.vbox)

    def add_button(self):
        self.scroll.add_button()

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
main = MainWindow()
main.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```